# startActivity runtime exception?? what is wrong?

Tags: android, exception

```
    09-12 13:11:49.400: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3465): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-12 13:11:49.400: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3465): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to pause activity {fy.aa.tablet/fy.aa.tablet.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-12 13:11:49.400: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3465):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2490)
09-12 13:11:49.400: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3465):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2447)
09-12 13:11:49.400: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3465):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handlePauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2425)
09-12 13:11:49.400: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3465):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:122)
09-12 13:11:49.400: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3465):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1012)
09-12 13:11:49.400: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3465):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-12 13:11:49.400: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3465):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
09-12 13:11:49.400: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3465):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4028)
09-12 13:11:49.400: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3465):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-12 13:11:49.400: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3465):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
09-12 13:11:49.400: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3465):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:844)
09-12 13:11:49.400: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3465):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
09-12 13:11:49.400: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3465):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-12 13:11:49.400: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3465): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-12 13:11:49.400: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3465):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onSaveInstanceState(ViewPager.java:507)
09-12 13:11:49.400: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3465):     at android.view.View.dispatchSaveInstanceState(View.java:8258)
09-12 13:11:49.400: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3465):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchSaveInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:1990)
09-12 13:11:49.400: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3465):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchSaveInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:1996)
09-12 13:11:49.400: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3465):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchSaveInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:1996)
09-12 13:11:49.400: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3465):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchSaveInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:1996)
09-12 13:11:49.400: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3465):     at android.view.View.saveHierarchyState(View.java:8241)
09-12 13:11:49.400: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3465):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.saveHierarchyState(PhoneWindow.java:1603)
09-12 13:11:49.400: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3465):     at android.app.Activity.onSaveInstanceState(Activity.java:1164)
09-12 13:11:49.400: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3465):     at android.app.Activity.performSaveInstanceState(Activity.java:1114)
09-12 13:11:49.400: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3465):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnSaveInstanceState(Instrumentation.java:1184)
09-12 13:11:49.400: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3465):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2472)
09-12 13:11:49.400: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3465):     ... 12 more
```

program crashed here:

```
  videolarGallery = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.video_gallery);
           videolarGallery.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
                try {
                    currVideo = (Video)videolarGallery.getAdapter().getItem(position);
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.setClass(myAct, deneme.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Logging.TraceMessage(e.getMessage(), Logging.ERROR, "videolarGallery.onItemClick()");
                }           
            }

           });
```

Comment: You better add some relevant code, or this question will probably get closed.

Comment: posting `onCreate()` of `MainActivity` may better help us to find the problem

Comment: This is a reported issue: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=19917

Comment: I disagree that this should be closed. It's a real question I used to solve the problem described.

Comment: Why is this closed? This helped me solved my problem.

Answer (score 3):

```
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onSaveInstanceState(ViewPager.java:507)
```

You didn't assign an adapter to your ViewPager (or not in the correct way). The mAdapter member variable of the `ViewPager` is `null` while calling `ViewPager.onSaveInstanceState()`.

See the [ViewPager source](http://google.com/codesearch#ZC36RCOTv_k/trunk/extras/android/compatibility/v4/src/java/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.java&q=ViewPager%20package%3aandroid&type=cs), line 507.

Comment: Even if I do not use, i must set it's adapter. I set a adapter and list what have not an item.

haberPager.setAdapter(new AwesomePagerAdapter(mActivity, 0, new ArrayList<Haber>()) );

Comment: Especially if you don't use `setAdapter()`. That should be the problem. You *have* to call it, because you *have* to set an adapter.

Answer (score 1):

in Your exception

```
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onSaveInstanceState(ViewPager.java:507)
09-12 13:11:49.400: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3465):     at android.view.View.dispatchSaveInstanceState(View.java:8258)
```

In ViewPager class  line no. 507 someone is null also check this View.java:8258

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely due to assignment of some null pointer value in Activity `MainActivity`.
If you post some code from this activity then that will be easier to rectify the problem.

Comment: i just intent startActivity(), i add some code in question.